# ADODB Command only retrieves one field

Tags: c#, .net, adodb

Fellow coders,

I'm using an ADODB command to pull some information out of a database, which consists of several fields. However, when I run the code, it only ever pulls out one field, and it's always the same one. I'm using MoveNext properly as far as I can tell, and I'm nested within an EOF while loop.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
if (!rsStbDetails.EOF)
{
    while (!rsStbDetails.EOF)
    {
        foreach (ADODB.Field f in rsStbDetails.Fields)
        {
           if (f.Value == null)
           {
               f.Value = 0;
           }

           switch (f.Name)
           {
               // There's a load of case statements here to manipulate the values being read in        
               default:
                   SetValue(id, f.Name, f.Value, f.Position);
                   break;
           }
        }
    }
    rsStbDetails.MoveNext();
}
```

Any ideas?
Cheers

EDIT: Here's the code I'm using to set up my connection:

```
objComm.ActiveConnection = conSQL;
objComm.CommandType = CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc;
objComm.CommandText = "Service.GetDetails";

objComm.Parameters.Append(objComm.CreateParameter("@Node", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 50, "NAME"));
objComm.Parameters.Append(objComm.CreateParameter("@Box", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 20, ""));
objComm.Parameters.Append(objComm.CreateParameter("@Num", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 20, 0));
objComm.Parameters.Append(objComm.CreateParameter("@Exclude", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 20, iExclude));

objComm.Parameters[1].Value = Right((string)GetProperty(id, "SName", role), 8);
```

Comment: Don't you think that `rsStbDetails.MoveNext();` should be inside `While` loop ??

Comment: Which kind of sql statement is executed to fill rsStbDetails?

Comment: @ADC I'm using the following to execute the statement:

`object Params = objComm.Parameters;
 rsStbDetails = objComm.Execute(out dummy, ref Params, (int)ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc);`

The `dummy` is just an empty object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should at least move `rsStbDetails.MoveNext();` one brace up :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Gerald. Unfortunately, I'm still only getting the same record. I'm stepping through my code, but the read-in value is always "Name". I've ran a query on it using SQL Server Management Studio, and the data is returned fully, so it seems to be the retriever.

Comment: Could you somehow check the count (or contents) of `rsStbDetails.Fields`? Are all fields in there?

Comment: If I use a Watch, the count only ever stays at 1 field. I've appended my original post to include my connection setup details.

Answer (score 1):

add this line inside the while loop: `rsStbDetails.MoveNext();` One more thing, I suggest that you have to use `ADONet` technology since you are in the `.net` enviroment.

**[This link is a very good place to learn `ADO NET` technology.](http://csharp.net-informations.com/ado.net/csharp-ado.net-architecture.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue is server-side and has nothing to do with my code. I've accepted Gerald's answer for pointing out the incorrect MoveNext() placement. Thanks anyway, chaps.